# SQl Output to CSV WITHOUT single Quotes

Tags: sql, csv, sybase-asa

I am running a query on Adaptive Server Anywhere v7.

```
select customerinfo.customerid, Name, Address1, Address2, City, State, ZIP, Country from customerinfo, addressinfo
where customerinfo.customerid = addressinfo.customerid
and MEMBER = (Date(GetDate()-4))
and addressinfo.addresstype = 's';
Output to C:\SamplePacks.CSV
```

Output is:

123, 'name','address1,'address2'.....

Is there a way to run the query so that the single quotes DO NOT show?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [doc](http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/dbreference/output-statement.html)

> QUOTE clause   The QUOTE clause is for the TEXT output format only.
>   The quote string is placed around string values. The default is a
>   single quote ('). If ALL is specified in the QUOTE clause, the quote
>   string is placed around all values, not just around strings. To
>   suppress quoting, specify empty single quotes. For example, QUOTE ''.

So it seems that you should do

```
Output to 'C:\SamplePacks.CSV' QUOTE ''
```